# Implementing a phase-neutral band-pass filter using SciPy

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, bandpass

Does the following code properly implement a phase-neutral band-pass filter using SciPy?

```
freq_fraction = FREQ / (SAMPLE_RATE/2)
sharpness = 0.1
filter_length=128
fir = sig.firwin(filter_length, [freq_fraction*(1-sharpness),freq_fraction*(1+sharpness)], pass_zero=False )
filtered = sig.lfilter( fir, 1, data_to_filter )
filtered = sig.lfilter( fir, 1,filtered[::-1] )[::-1]
```

The code is based on the answer to:

[Is it correct to subtract a low-pass filtered signal from the original signal and use the result as a "high-pass"?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3182/is-it-correct-to-subtract-a-low-pass-filtered-signal-from-the-original-signal-an/3250#3250)

which doesn't give a final code listing for how to maintain phase neutrality.  I'm assuming it's just a matter of running the filter forward and backwards but want to double-check.

Also, if there are better/different ways of doing this (other than the remez and firwin2 methods listed in the other question) I'd love to know.

Comment: What does "phase-neutral" mean?

Comment: @endolith: I assume he's looking for zero-phase filtering. The code above looks to implement forward-backward filtering, similar to MATLAB's `filtfilt` function.

Comment: By "phase-neutral" I mean not affecting the phase of the signal.  In other words, key points in the signal should not be moved forward or backward in time.

Comment: I this question answered? If so, you may accept the answer to close the issue and show other's "this is solved".

Comment: Doesn't seem answered -- no one ever said if the code will do the right thing or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about [scipy.signal.filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) and [scipy.signal.butter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html#scipy.signal.butter) filter? See the example at the bottom of the documentation.

Here's another example with and without phase neutrality: [Applying filter in scipy.signal: Use lfilter or filtfilt?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/applying-filter-in-scipy-signal-use-lfilter-or-filtfilt)

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the frequency response (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_response) of the filter and see yourself.

Comment: While I tend to agree that people should try and do as much as they can on their own, generally they are here asking questions because they are struggling with some part of the process. Therefore simply telling them to 'see for themselves' doesn't really add much as an answer.

Comment: It's a reasonable suggestion.  I've run the code already and it seems to work but wanted to hear if there were any flaws with the approach or better ways of doing it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would the frequency response graph look if there is an induced phase offset vs. not?